# How to check for PyWin time type

Tags: python, com, pywin32

I'm trying to check if the data returned by PyWin in a COM interface with Excel is of the type 'time'.

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from pywintypes import Time
cellToTest = Dispatch('Excel.Application').Sheets('SomeSheet').Range('SomeCell').Value
if type( cellToTest ) == Time:
    print 'It\'s an excel time type'
```

Because this: `type(Time)`

Returns this: `<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>`

Yet this: `type(cellToTest)`

Returns this: `<type 'time'>`

Answer (score 1):

*Time* is not a type but a a function which returns a new time object (http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/pywintypes__Time_meth.html). I don't know where the actual types are hosted within the win32 package but you could create an arbitrary time object and ask for its type:

```
type(cellToTest) == type(Time(1))
```

Comment: Christian, thank you. This works, but I was really hoping to get the type itself. +1 for the workaround though.

Comment: You are welcome. For the type, ask on the pywin32 mailing list. I am sure you will get an answer within hours.